# How can I set the time out, in the command and the connection?

Tags: c#, ado.net, settimeout, sqlcommand, connection-timeout

this is my code in the dataset.cs.
what do I have to add for set the timeout in the connection and the command?

```
namespace M_Report
{


    partial class A_DBDataSet
    {

        partial class VP_DataTable
        {
        }
    }
}


namespace M_Report.A_DBDataSetTableAdapters
{
    partial class VD_TableAdapter
    {
    }

    public partial class VP_rofitsTableAdapter {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have literally no idea what you asking

Comment: I'm guessing by the fact that you accepted an answer that your reffering to ado.net `SqlCommand` object. Please try and be more clear in your questions

Comment: thanks! I find some codeto add in the dataset.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in the DataSet.cs:

```
namespace P.A_DBDataSetTableAdapters
{
    public partial class VD_TableAdapter
    {
        public int CommandTimeout
        {
            set
            {
                int i = 0;
                while ((i < this.CommandCollection.Length))
                {
                    if ((this.CommandCollection[i] != null))
                        this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout = value;
                    i = (i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this code in the Form.cs:
`this.vD_TableAdapter.CommandTimeout = 1800;`

Comment: Works Good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a timeout for a particular query, then CommandTimeout is the way.

```
command.CommandTimeout = 60; //default is 30 seconds.
```

Or you can also add it in the connection string

```
connect timeout=180;
```